# Use float as array key

Tags: javascript

I want to use an array to look up a value given a key. AFAIK, it should be possible when converting the float to a string, like the second example below: ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezq9cuzh/))

```
arr = [];
arr[1.3] = "One point three";
console.log(arr.length);

arr = [];
arr["1.3"] = "One point three";
console.log(arr.length);
```

But both result in a zero-length array. What am I doing wrong? I.e. how can I look up an object/string/whatever given a float value?

It would be awesome to have a reference guide on common operations when using having to look up values, such as:

- get an element, given a float key
- get total number of elements
- test if float key exists
- put new float key / value pair
- and maybe others, such as loop through all keys/values

Comment: index should be integer for an array..... use object instead and set property `arr = {};
arr['1.3'] = "One point three";
console.log(Object.keys(arr).length);`

Comment: `length` doesn't include non-integer keys, otherwise it would have to count itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array's index must be an integer for adding it as an array item. If you will pass to the `[]` not an integer, it will be added as a `property`.

```js
arr = [];
arr[1.3] = "One point three";

console.log(arr.length);

console.log(arr.hasOwnProperty('1.3'));

console.log(Object.keys(arr).length);
```

Comment: Array entries are also properties.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but it seems you are trying to create a dict. I would just use an object like others have suggested.

```
var arr = {
    1.2: 'One Point Three'
}

arr[1.2] or arr["1.2"] // One Point Three

or you can use es6 Map

var arr = new Map()
    arr.set(1.3, "One Point Three")
    arr.get(1.3) // One Point Three 
    arr.size // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

An array takes an integer value as index.

You should be using an `Object` for this kind of mapping.

```
var arr = {};
arr[1.3] = "One point three";
console.log(Object.keys(arr).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suren's answer was the first, and gave me what I needed to establish a reference of operations:

---

---

**Insert an item:**

```
var x = 1.3;

// Not actually an array! arr.length will be undefined. Although
// an array could still be used, it seems
var arr = {}; 

arr[x] = "One point three";
```

**Count items:**

```
Object.keys(arr).length
```

**Test if key exists:**

```
arr.hasOwnProperty(x)
```

**Get an element:**

```
arr[x]
```

**Loop through key/value pairs**

```
for (key in arr)
{
    var value = arr[key];
}
```

---

---

**Interesting quirks**

+1 to James Emanon for several points: Firstly, showing that a string is not necessary for lookup:

```
arr[1.3] // works
```

Secondly, the array can be defined as an object like so:

```
arr = {
    1.3: "One point three"
};
```

Thirdly, ES6 provides a `Map` object. Will be useful.